# How to get date format in required format like 'dd/MM/yyyy' , 'MMddyyyy', MMM, etc

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have date in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format and I need to get date format according input format. Input format will be anyone of 'MMddyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd' , MM, MMM, MMMM, yyyy.

Format:'MMddyyyy':: Output Should be: '02232015'

Format:'yyyy-MM-dd':: Output Should be: '2015-02-23'

Format:'yyyy/MM/dd':: Output Should be: '2015/02/23'

Format:'MM':: Output Should be: '02'

Format:'MMM':: Output Should be: 'Feb'

Format:'MMMM':: Output Should be: 'February'

I am trying with

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But it is not working. It give invalid date format error.

So can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: DateTime.Parse is how you get/convert string data into a DateTime var, the format indicates the pattern of the string.  You will never get a DAteTime var which is just "Feb", if that is what you are after.  It does not "format the date" because dates do not have a format - they are simply a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing about parsing a string to a `DateTime` with getting a *specific* string representation of a `DateTime`.

If you wanna get a textual representation of a `DateTime` (like `2015-02-23`, `2015/02/23` and `February` as you said), you can use [`.ToString()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an *english-based* culture.

For your string results with order, you can get them as;

```
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MMddyyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 02232015
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 2015-02-23
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 2015/02/23
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MM", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 02
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MMM", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // Feb
yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // February
```

If you *try* to say like; you have these formatted strings and do you wanna parse these formatted strings to `DateTime`, you can use [this `DateTime.ParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `string[]` as a format.

```
var formats = new string[]
{
     "MMddyyyy",
     "yyyy-MM-dd",
     "yyyy/MM/dd",
     "MM",
     "MMM",
     "MMMM"
}

var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: I tried with  yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MMddyyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US")); It is working. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to parse as following
     yourDateTimevalue.ToString("MMyyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
and yourDateTimevalue is "022015", it is giving error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

Comment: @Hanumantha You still mixing _parsing_ with _getting a string representation of a DateTime_. Please re-read my answer. `DateTime.ToString()` method generates `string` representation of a `DateTime` in a _specific_ format you want. If you want to _parse_ a `string` **to** `DateTime`, you need to use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` methods like; `var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("022015", "MMyyyy", null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString() with format

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
string format="MMddyyyy";
DateTime.Now().ToString(format);
```